# Convert timestamp to string from firebase

Tags: date, timestamp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t3pK.png)I accessed the timestamp from firestore and printed it as an string but it's not showing in date format! I'm not being able to print timestamp inside Text widget without converting it into string fromat either.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Firestore function, than the easiest way to convert a timestamp to a JavaScript date or as you said string is like this:

```
new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString()
```

The timestamp is an object with seconds and nanoseconds, you create an date instance, pass the timestamp seconds and multiply with 1000. Now you can format this as you want.